# Reference cell value in AVERAGEIFS formula

Tags: excel-formula

In excel, I am trying to average a group of cells less than a value (contained within a cell) and greater than another value (contained within another cell).  Is there a way to write a formula (I have been using AVERAGEIFS) which can automatically reference a particular cell.  It is very time consuming and error prone to manually alter the formula over several workbook sheets.

I have written the following formula by manually entering in the values calculated in another cell.

=AVERAGEIFS(Q2:Q97,Q2:Q97,"<790",Q2:Q97,">394")

Is there a way to change this formula so that it automatically reference, for example (this throws an error in excel).

=AVERAGEIFS(Q2:Q97,Q2:Q97,C5,Q2:Q97,C7)

Answer (score 2):

AVERAGEIFS use strings as the criteria: `"<790"`

So you can concatenate a string with the Cell reference: `"<" & C5`

So:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Q2:Q97,Q2:Q97,"<" & C5,Q2:Q97,">" & C7)
```

Comment: Thank goodness!  I knew it was something small like that, but I couldn't find the correct code online.  Thanks sooooo much.